# how to disable temporarily a button Android

Tags: android, button

I would like to disable an android button temporarily. I've used the method Button.setEnabled(false) but this disables by button definitely, my button should be disabled for example just for one second

Comment: Using a timer you have to enable it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the following code to make button enable after 1 sec

```
final Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

btn.setEnabled(false);

new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                LoginActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        btn.setEnabled(true);

                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
```