# Disable back button for temporary time

Tags: android

I know this question have been asked many times around here, but i didn't find the propert answer for my issue.

this code can disable back button:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Do Here what ever you want do on back press;
}
```

but is there anyway that i can disable back button for a temporary time,not for the whole Activity ?

Comment: Did you checked this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14810960/2194831)

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893340/how-to-disable-temporarily-a-button-android

Comment: @Krrishnaaaa , :) how strange !! i read that question before asking mine, but i didn't notice that asnwer .. thank you .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

nice answer by Dixit. Just another option

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (keyCode == KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (condition) {
            result =  true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

N.B ..

- it will work on ancient version also
- returning true from onKeyDown consumes the default behavior

Comment: Selected as the correct answer for supporting all versions & timimg of the answer. thank you..

Answer (score 3):

You have to set on `boolean flag` where you have to require disable back button set `flag value true`;

In **onBackPressed()** you have to put condition as per **@Dixit** says

```
@Override
   public void onBackPressed() {

    if(condition to check){
       // this block disable back button

    }else{
       // this block enable back button
        super.onBackPressed();       

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable backbutton for certain time use this,

```
//for 5 sec = 5000
countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(5000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            txtWait.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.errorcolor));
            txtWait.setText("Wait( " + millisUntilFinished / 1000+" sec)");
            onBackPressed();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            YourActivityName.super.onBackPressed();

        }
    }.start();
```

And in the override method:

```
     @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        //super.onBackPressed();  commented this to disable the back press
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Full working code:

```
YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

   boolean isBackButtonDisabled = false;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setContentView(R.layout.somelayout);

         disableBackButton(4000);    //<--Back button is disabled

   }


   @Override
   public void onBackPressed(){

        if(!sBackButtonDisabled){
              super.onBackPressed();
        }
   }

   private void disableBackButton(final int timeInMilis){

    if(!isBackButtonDisabled) {

        isBackButtonDisabled = true;             //<-- Keep it outside Thread code 

        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(timeInMilis);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                } finally {
                    isBackButtonDisabled = false;
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
}

}
```

> **Note:** You can use `disableBackButton(time)` in other scenarios as well. For example Button click. If
>   you click button multiple times the Thread will only run once. Because in this code 
>   `isBackButtonDisable` variable is thread-safe "in a way".